# Linq type conversion delegate for .First method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, ienumerable

Using this method below how come I can write this without error

```
return _session.Query<Data.Model.User>().Select(_userMapper.CreateUser)
          .AsQueryable();
```

but writing this

```
return _session.Query<Data.Model.User>().Where(x => x.Username == username)
         .First(_userMapper.CreateUser);
```

produces an error.

```
public User CreateUser(Data.Model.User modelUser)
{
    return new User{UserId = modelUser.UserId, Username = modelUser.Username,
                    Email = modelUser.Email, Firstname = modelUser.Firstname,
                    Lastname = modelUser.lastname};
}
```

Whether returning a collection or a single item I want it to be converted by the create user method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Select` before `First()`:

```
return _session.Query<Data.Model.User>()
               .Where(x => x.Username == username)
               .Select(_userMapper.CreateUser)
               .First();
```

Or:

```
return _session.Query<Data.Model.User>()
               .Select(_userMapper.CreateUser)
               .First(x => x.Username == username);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return _userMapper.CreateUser(_session.Query<Data.Model.User>().First(x => x.Username == username));
```